# Custom navigation bar height and view

Tags: ios4

I want to have a naviagtion bar that is at least the double height.
In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in my appdelegate.m file, I've added
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 100.f);
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:frame];
But when I run the app the top part of the table view is behind the bottom of the navigation bar.

How do I resize the table view so it`s not behind the navigation bar?

Thank's

// Sven

Answer (score 4):

If you want to resize your navigation bar in all application viewConttrollers, you can override sizeThatFits:(CGRect) rect method in UINavigationBar category

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (bigSize) 

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
   CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,100);
   return newSize;
}

@end
```

Comment: It seems this method works only in subclass(when use category, it'll not be called, including the `drawRect:` method). Anyway, that's what I want! Thanks! :)

Comment: @tt.Kilew: But how to manage back button frame ? back button appeared and the bottom of navigation bar !